# How to get the authenticated user avatar in the header blade?

Tags: laravel

in profile page a user has an option to choose an avatar picture, and in the `header.blade.php` I want  to check if the user has chosen an avatar ,if yes, then display the avatar picture next to the user name.
now in `profile.blade.php` I can show the chosen avatar with this line of code

```
<img style="border-radius: 50%;" src="{{url('/')}}/Uploads/avatars/{{$myAvatar->image}}" height="60px;" width="60px;" alt="" id="avatar-preload" name="avatar-preload">
```

in profile controller i have index function which passes `$myAvatar` to `profile.blade.php`

```
public function index()
{
    $user= User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $myAvatar = Avatar::find($user->avatar_id);
    return view('admin.profile.index')
           ->with('avatars', Avatar::all())
           ->with('myAvatar',$myAvatar);
}
```

I want to apply the same logic to bring the avatar picture to `header.blade.php` but I dont have a controller to send data to the the header blade through it, how can I do that?

Every user now has an `avatar_id` which refers to the id of the chosen avatar in the avatar table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model you could define a relationship with Avatar

```
public function avatar()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Avatar::class, 'id','avatar_id');
}
```

Then in your blade, you could use `Auth::user()->avatar` anywhere you want.

Comment: but can I use this syntax in the blade to get the image as I did in the profile <img  src="{{url('/')}}/Uploads/avatars/{{$Auth::user()->avatar->image}}"> ?   image is an attribute in avatar which is actually the name of the avatar

Comment: Yes. You can use like that.

Answer (score 1):

Create A Model Relationship

```
public function getAvtar()
{

    return Avatar::where('your filed name',Auth::user()->id);

}
```

Then Call Like This

```
Auth::user()->getAvtar()
```